# Downgrading 18.04 kernel 5.0 to the original kernel that came with 18.04

Tags: kernel

A year or so ago I installed 18.04
Now I've installed 18.04.3 18.04.2 and finally 18.04 to an other hard disk on the same PC and the kernel is always 5.0.0-27-generic, how can I get back the 4.xxx that originally came with 18.04 (and 18.04.1 and 18.04.2, according to google wisdom 5.xxx was introduced with 18.04.3).

I've got a third party closed source library that fails to install on kernel 5 and I've traced the problem to a changed header file in that comes with the kernel. (Linux 5.0: macro "access_ok" passed 3 arguments, but takes just 2).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is quite easy. Run in a terminal:

```
sudo apt install linux-generic
```

That will install the 4.15 kernel and related meta packages.

Then boot with that kernel using grub menu and remove all 5.0 kernel packages.

Comment: are there security risks and bug issues in using 4.15?  I posted elsewhere you answered about a wifi adapter and this: https://github.com/nazar-pc/RTL8814AU only supports up to 4.16 so I was going to downgrade but hesitating.

Comment: There are no risks of using the 4.15 kernel on 18.04 because it is a supported non-HWE kernel. But there are drivers that are available for current kernels too.

Comment: I saw this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1185952/need-rtl8814au-driver-for-kernel-5-3-on-ubuntu-19-10.  I Googled, "ac68 driver for kernel 5".  Can you assist?  I'm on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: I have no idea what ac68 is. If it is an RTL8814 device, then search for current drivers.

Comment: it's this adapter: https://www.asus.com/ca-en/Networking/USB-AC68/HelpDesk_Download/  The download with Linux drivers have errors on both `./install.sh` and `sudo make && sudo make install` which I have contacted ASUS about but I will search for Realtek now, thanks.

Comment: Check `lsusb` to see what device is there. Or ask a new question for help.

Comment: I tried this, but when I run uname -r, it still shows me the original version 5.4.0-1029-aws. I understand that this might be a different issue, can you please let me know what needs be done here?

Comment: This is a different issue. You can ask another question.