# Need rtl8814au driver for kernel 5.3 on Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: wireless, 19.10

On Ubuntu 19.04 I had current rtl8812au (AC1200) and rtl8814au (AC1750) dkms drivers for my USB wireless dongles installed and running fine.

They both broke after I upgraded to Ubuntu 19.10.

I've been able to find a replacement/newer rtl8812au driver that works with kernel 5.3 on Ubuntu 19.10.

I haven't been able to find a replacement/newer rtl8814au driver that works with kernel 5.3 on Ubuntu 19.10.

Github.com has a number of rtl8814au drivers available, even some that proport to compile with kernel 5.2. I believe that I've tried about 6 different rtl8814au drivers from github, but none of them work, even though some of them do compile with kernel 5.3.

Does anybody know of a working rtl8814au driver that works with kernel 5.3 on Ubuntu 19.10?

Comment: Did you found https://github.com/gordboy/rtl8812au

Comment: @nobody yes, thanks, I found that one. It's for the rtl8812au, and I need the rtl8814au.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
sudo apt install git dkms
git clone https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au.git
cd rtl8812au
sudo ./dkms-install.sh
```

It worked for me on my rtl8814au device, it should work for rtl8812au, rtl8814au, and rtl8821au devices.  For some strange reason the driver didn't want to work until after a second reboot.  I don't know why

Secure boot needs to be disabled in BIOS, check results for `mokutil --sb-state`

With recent changes you need to

```
sudo apt install git dkms
git clone https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8814au.git
cd rtl8814au
sudo make dkms_install
```

Reboot

Comment: That seems to work! Thanks!

Comment: This also works for my TP Link T2U Nano (id 2357:011e) on kernel 5.3.0-24, it uses the 8821 driver. Thanks!

Comment: Additional step: `sudo modprobe 88XXau`. Driver works for me. Thanks!

Comment: Can confirm this works even with 18814au device. Dongle lit up instantly (without needing modprobe).

Comment: Tested this with Linksys AC1200 Dual bank Wireless-AC USB Adapter (RTL8812AU). 

Bus 001 Device 004: ID 13b1:003f Linksys WUSB6300 802.11a/b/g/n/ac Wireless Adapter [Realtek RTL8812AU]

Worked like a charm. I am on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (Kernel: 5.3.0-42-generic)

Comment: Works on Fossa 20.04 too, with a Jensen Eagle 100AC USB adapter. Thanks!

Comment: I think it could also work with the secure-boot turned on. Something to do with MOK enrollment etc. Basically followed the instructions during the installation. It works perfectly !

Comment: This works on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with ASUS AC1900 USB-AC68 adapter on Lenovo T420, thanks!

Comment: Thanks Bro! Works great. On ```5.4.0-48-generic```.

Comment: rtl8814au just got its own repo yesterday and has been disabled in aircrack-ng/rtl8812au. Use https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8814au instead