# TP-Link Archer T2U Plus not working on Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, tp-link

I just got a TP-Link Archer T2U Plus. I couldn't get it working on Ubuntu 19.10. with Kernel 5.3.0-24-generic.

my lsusb:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:5621 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. HD WebCam
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0aa7 Intel Corp.
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0581:0105 Racal Data Group
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 2357:0120 TP-Link 802.11ac WLAN Adapter
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

As you can see it is listed, however I cannot use it to connect to a network.

Is there any official or unofficial driver which I can use for Linux (not just Ubuntu but Raspbian as well)?

I would really appreciate your input.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TP-Link AC600 Archer T2U Nano driver for Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1149117/tp-link-ac600-archer-t2u-nano-driver-for-ubuntu-18-04) Search before asking, it was very easy to find.

Comment: @mikewhatever I don't know if that works on 5.3 but https://askubuntu.com/q/1185952 does

Comment: Hi guys, thank you for your replies! Sorry for littering the site with the same question. Jeremy31, your suggestion worked for me! Thank you very much for the quick help guys the wifi dongle works well now!