# Probelms with Loading Realtek rtl8812AU driver in Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: drivers, wireless, usb, 19.10, realtek-wireless

I have a Asus USB-AC53 Nano wifi adapter that has stopped working after a recent ubuntu software update.  The adapter still works on other machines.

I am on 19.10 and the output of uname -a is:

```
jon@jon-basemet:~$ uname -a
Linux jon-basemet 5.3.0-26-generic #28-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 18 05:37:46 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

DKMS Status:

```
sudo dkms status
nvidia, 390.129, 5.3.0-24-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia, 390.129, 5.3.0-26-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8812au, 4.2.2, 5.3.0-26-generic, x86_64: installed
```

I followed these two sets of instructions:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git
git clone https://github.com/gnab/rtl8812au.git
sudo cp -r rtl8812au  /usr/src/rtl8812au-4.2.2
sudo dkms add -m rtl8812au -v 4.2.2
sudo dkms build -m rtl8812au -v 4.2.2
sudo dkms install -m rtl8812au -v 4.2.2
```

and

```
sudo apt-get purge rtl8812au-dkms 
sudo apt-get install git
git clone https://github.com/jeremyb31/rtl8812AU.git
sudo dkms add ./rtl8812AU
sudo dkms install rtl8812AU/5
```

Neither of these solutions worked.

LSUSB(note, the edimax is a differnt usb wifi antenna that works:
$ lsusb

```
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 7392:7811 Edimax Technology Co., Ltd EW-7811Un 802.11n Wireless Adapter [Realtek RTL8188CUS]
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0b05:184c ASUSTek Computer, Inc. 802.11ac NIC
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 058f:6361 Alcor Micro Corp. Multimedia Card Reader
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 413c:3012 Dell Computer Corp. Optical Wheel Mouse
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 046a:0180 Cherry GmbH wired keyboard
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

```
$ modinfo 8812au | grep A811
alias:          usb:v0BDApA811d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v7392pA811d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
```

```
lsmod | grep 8812
8812au                991232  0
```

Running journalctl --follow and inserting the Asus antenna (without the edimax one installed) gives the following:

```
$ journalctl --follow
Jan 16 08:06:07 jon-basemet kernel: usb 2-2: new high-speed USB device number 10 using ehci-pci
Jan 16 08:06:07 jon-basemet kernel: usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0b05, idProduct=184c, bcdDevice= 2.10
Jan 16 08:06:07 jon-basemet kernel: usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Jan 16 08:06:07 jon-basemet kernel: usb 2-2: Product: 802.11ac NIC
Jan 16 08:06:07 jon-basemet kernel: usb 2-2: Manufacturer: Realtek
Jan 16 08:06:07 jon-basemet kernel: usb 2-2: SerialNumber: 123456
Jan 16 08:06:07 jon-basemet mtp-probe[5875]: checking bus 2, device 10: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-2"
Jan 16 08:06:07 jon-basemet mtp-probe[5875]: bus: 2, device: 10 was not an MTP device
Jan 16 08:06:07 jon-basemet mtp-probe[5878]: checking bus 2, device 10: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-2"
Jan 16 08:06:07 jon-basemet mtp-probe[5878]: bus: 2, device: 10 was not an MTP device
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Need rtl8814au driver for kernel 5.3 on Ubuntu 19.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1185952/need-rtl8814au-driver-for-kernel-5-3-on-ubuntu-19-10)

Answer (score 5):

I'm having the same issue but after distribution upgrade now on kernal 5.3.0-26-generic. `sudo apt install  rtl8812au-dkms` had always worked after new kernel upgrade but not now so your not alone.

---

Ok after some searching this worked for me:

```bash
sudo apt install git dkms
git clone https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au.git
cd rtl8812au
sudo make dkms_install
```

Got my answer from here maybe it helps [Need rtl8814au driver for kernel 5.3 on Ubuntu 19.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1185952/need-rtl8814au-driver-for-kernel-5-3-on-ubuntu-19-10)

The person posting answer also said this:

> It worked for me on my rtl8814au device, it should work for rtl8812au, rtl8814au, and rtl8821au devices. For some strange reason the driver didn't want to work until after a second reboot. I don't know why

Hope it helps.

Comment: Ok after some searching this worked for me.                                                                                                                                                                              sudo apt install git dkms
git clone https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au.git
cd rtl8812au
sudo ./dkms-install.sh

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, but unfortunately it didn't work for me.  I removed the last drive I tried from dkms, erased the source files and then followed your instructions.  The driver installed with no warnings but after a reboot, my usb antenna is still not recognized.

Comment: @EdwardI Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I've consolidated the information from [that comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1203343/probelms-with-loading-realtek-rtl8812au-driver-in-ubuntu-19-10/1203576#comment2018973_1203576) and [that answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1203636/22949) into this. I am assuming, based on context, that you're the same person as [that user](https://askubuntu.com/users/1035065/edward-i). Please feel free to re-edit if you don't like, or otherwise wish to improve further, on these changes. You may want to get your accounts merged; you can use https://askubuntu.com/contact.

Comment: This doesn't fix this device as it is RTL8822BU

Comment: @Jeremy31 Thanks for pointing this out. Not sure how I came to the idea that it was a RTL8812AU.  I tried your driver, but it did not work either...