# getting alfa awus036ach to work on my pc

Tags: drivers, alfa-wireless

I have searched everywhere for this, but I just cant find a solution to it. I am tryint to set up a alfa awus036ach on kubuntu. I have a wifi card in my pc (dont know if its affecting it) but whenver I pull a iwconfig, whether its plugged in or not, It just doesnt show up. I have tried installing drivers to solve the issue, but I am new to ubuntu (and linux in general) and have been having a hard time getting it to work. someone please help.

```
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 002: ID 062a:5918 MosArt Semiconductor Corp. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 003: ID 0b05:18f3 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. AURA LED Controller
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 8087:0029 Intel Corp. 
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 2516:0051 Cooler Master Co., Ltd. AMD SR4 lamplight Control
Bus 003 Device 008: ID 0bda:8812 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8812AU 802.11a/b/g/n/ac 2T2R DB WLAN Adapter
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 1a2c:2124 China Resource Semico Co., Ltd USB Keyboard
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

T:  Bus=03 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=03 Cnt=02 Dev#=  4 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=0bda ProdID=8812 Rev=00.00
S:  Manufacturer=Realtek
S:  Product=802.11n NIC
S:  SerialNumber=123456
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#=0x0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 5 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=(none)
    
8192cu, 1.11: added
rtl8812au, 4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg, 5.4.0-60-generic, x86_64: installed

    SecureBoot disabled
Platform is in Setup Mode
```

Comment: What is "awus036ach"? Which Kubuntu release you are using?

Comment: it is a wireless usb wifi adapter, and my version is 20.04.1 LTS

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lsusb` command.

Comment: just edited it.

Comment: The adapter was not connected. This output makes no sense. Plug in adapter, run the command again and give the output.

Comment: plugged in the adapter

Comment: Let's debug it further, please post output of `usb-devices | awk '/0bda/' RS=` and `sudo modprobe 8812au` and `dkms status`.

Comment: just added the stuff into the post

Comment: Can you format your text yourself next time. Select it and click the `{}` icon above.

Comment: Please add `sudo mokutil --sb-state`

Comment: If it shows that SB is disabled, then run `sudo apt purge rtl8812au-dkms` and use this method https://askubuntu.com/a/1203576/167850

Comment: ok. thank you for sinking so much time into this. it means alot

Comment: It should work. I think the drivers from the repo is broken. It was before, but I thought they fixed it.