# Is it still possible to install the Edimax AC1750 with kernel 5.X

Tags: wireless

I saw another post here for the Edimax Ac1750 and one guy had success installing it with kernel 5.x, but it did not work for me.

Is it still possible to make it work ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add details about what didn't work for you exactly.

Comment: See the accepted answer at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1185952/need-rtl8814au-driver-for-kernel-5-3-on-ubuntu-19-10

Comment: I did try the above solution, it goes without error. but still not working.

Comment: But i do see the USB key  lsusb
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 7392:a833 Edimax Technology Co., Ltd

Comment: What is result from terminal for `mokutil --sb-state`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help but I decided to changed the internal WIFI card instead because I always had problem with this card and Linux Mint, it would work then decided to stop, I had to go thrue a procedure and it would work for a while.

so I purchase an Intel7260HMW Dualband Wireless WiFi Card with Bluetooth 4.0, Mini PCI-E. Installed it and had nothing to do. it was recognize intantly.