# Netgear A6100 wireless adapter not working on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, 16.04, internet, realtek-wireless

I am using Netgear A6100 wireless adapter to connect my desktop to the wi-fi network. I am using a community wifi. On desktop, I have Ubuntu 16.04 with kernel version 4.15. I copied the driver from https://github.com/abperiasamy/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux, compiled and installed. I can see the available wifi networks. But when I connect and enter password, it always comes back saying authentication failed. I know for sure that the password is correct. What could be wrong and how to fix this ?

Thanks
Harsha

Comment: Is wpasupplicant installed? `dpkg -l wpa* | grep ii`. You might also look at the accepted answer at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1185952/need-rtl8814au-driver-for-kernel-5-3-on-ubuntu-19-10

Comment: Thanks. The steps in link worked.