# alfa wireless adapter / realtek rtl8812eu not compatible with Intel Wireless-AC 9560 WLAN WiFi 802.11ac

Tags: 18.04, wireless, kernel, realtek, iwlwifi

I tried many times to install (via apt get, dkms, git clone) the rtl8812au driver for the alfa AWUS036ACH adapter. Internally (xps 15) I have a Intel Wireless-AC 9560 WLAN WiFi 802.11ac so I need the backport iwlwifi to make it work).

Including :
[Need rtl8814au driver for kernel 5.3 on Ubuntu 19.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1185952/need-rtl8814au-driver-for-kernel-5-3-on-ubuntu-19-10)

When I search on ifconfig, iwconfig or airmon-ng is not found.

It does appear on 'lsusb'. 
Also:

```
modprobe rtl8812au
```

got:

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module rtl8812au not found in directory
 /lib/modules/5.3.0-40-generic
```

I have ubuntu 18.4 on kernel 5.3.0-40-generic
Also

```
 dkms status

 backport-iwlwifi, 8286, 4.15.0-88-generic, x86_64: installed
 backport-iwlwifi, 8286, 5.3.0-40-generic, x86_64: installed
 nvidia, 430.64, 4.15.0-88-generic, x86_64: installed
 nvidia, 430.64, 5.3.0-40-generic, x86_64: installed
 realtek-rtl88xxau, 5.6.4.2~20200201: added
 rtl8812au, 5.6.4.2, 5.3.0-40-generic, x86_64: installed
```

and ifconfig returns only my internal Broadcast module:

```
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Boucle locale)
        RX packets 7299  bytes 3293170 (3.2 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 7299  bytes 3293170 (3.2 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp59s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.43.29  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.43.255
        inet6 fe80::b309:b9d5:7c7e:e25c  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 4c:1d:96:6b:f6:c0  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 85586  bytes 97887163 (97.8 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 35860  bytes 8167108 (8.1 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

uname -r

```
 4.15.0-88-generic
```

lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net

```
  3b:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2723] (rev 1a)
Subsystem: Bigfoot Networks, Inc. Device [1a56:1654]
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
Kernel modules: iwlwifi
3c:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:525a] (rev 01)
```

PS: I also tried the kernel 5.3 but it didn't solve the problem immediatly and on my skylake processor was eating up all the battery. So the solution needs to be be using kernel 4.15+

Comment: uninstall the backport-iwlwifi as no other wifi device will work as long as it is installed

Comment: ah. my internal adapter is a broadcast (dell XPS 15) so if I uninstall that I fear I will lose my internal adapter. I cannot do that.

Comment: Why have you tagged 19.04?

Comment: Please edit the question to include results from terminal for `lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net; uname -r`

Comment: @Jeremy31 just did

Comment: Looks like you are in catch 22, the 5.3 kernels support your internal Intel device without the backports and that should allow the rtl8812au module to work but in 4.15 the Intel cannot work without the backports and that prevents the rtl8812au module from working

Comment: @Jeremy31 great. So no solution...