# A way to make backport iwlwifi compatible with other drivers

Tags: 18.04, kernel, iwlwifi, backport

I had found out that my Intel wireless adapter needs the backport on kernel 4.15 and at the same time my Alfa card needs realtek RTL8812AU. Also I cannot change kernel (skylake problem) More [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1213302/alfa-wireless-adapter-realtek-rtl8812eu-not-compatible-with-intel-wireless-ac)

Is there a way to keep backport iwlwifi open and install RTL8812AU so I can use the external card as well?
I will ask in another way: is there a way to have compatible using the same kernel:

- skylake processor
- RTL8812AU realtek adapter
- Intel Wireless-AC 9560 WLAN WiFi 802.11ac

Comment: Running two wireless dongles on the same network won't double your wireless throughput.

Comment: this is not the point. The other would be for monitor mode

Comment: That's important information and should be in your question. You should also make clear exactly which hardware you intend to use for monitor mode.

Comment: No the question is about using RTL8812AU with iwlwifi backport. Regardless of what I am using it for

Comment: The rtl8812au requires a different driver than iwlwifi, so the question is kind of moot. Do you have the proper rtl8812au driver in dkms format? What version? Why not just run the latest 5.3.x kernel and a rtl8812au dkms driver?

Comment: as I wrote 5+ kernels are not compatible with skylake processors

Comment: Do you mean that you can't run 5.x.x kernels because they have a perceived battery usage issue with skylake processors? I'm not sure I buy this. Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: I tried it and in a github post a kernel 5 developer advised users with skylake not to use it. If I found the post I will put the link