# ASUS AC56 Wifi driver problem

Tags: wireless, asus, 20.04, dkms

i have asus ac56 usb wifi adapter. I installed the rtl8812au-dkms package but my adapter is not recognized. Using Ubuntu 20.04

```
    dkms status
rtl8812au, 4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg, 5.4.0-26-generic, x86_64: installed


lssub:
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0b05:17d2 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. USB-AC56 802.11a/b/g/n/ac Wireless Adapter [Realtek RTL8812AU]
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1a2c:0043 China Resource Semico Co., Ltd USB Mouse
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1a2c:2d43 China Resource Semico Co., Ltd USB Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0bda:8179 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188EUS 802.11n Wireless Network Adapter
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

T:  Bus=03 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=00 Cnt=01 Dev#=  2 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=0b05 ProdID=17d2 Rev=00.00
S:  Manufacturer=Realtek
S:  Product=802.11n NIC
S:  SerialNumber=123456
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#=0x0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 5 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=(none)
```

`modinfo 8812au | grep -i 0b05`

```
alias: usb:v0B05p17D2ddcdscdpiciscipin
```

`dmesg | grep 8812`

```
[    3.151555] 8812au: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[    3.161338] 8812au: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[    3.162909] RTL871X: rtl8812au v4.3.8_12175.20140902
[    3.162968] Modules linked in: 8812au(OE+) snd_rawmidi amd_iommu_v2(+) fjes(-) aesni_intel(+) snd_seq gpu_sched crypto_simd ttm cryptd drm_kms_helper glue_helper snd_seq_device cfg80211 snd_timer wmi_bmof k10temp i2c_algo_bit fb_sys_fops joydev syscopyarea input_leds sysfillrect snd sysimgblt soundcore ccp mac_hid sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp drm parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_generic usbhid hid crc32_pclmul i2c_piix4 r8169 nvme ahci realtek nvme_core libahci wmi gpio_amdpt gpio_generic
[    3.163016]  ? _rtw_malloc+0x2d/0x2f [8812au]
[    3.163032]  ? _rtw_memcpy+0x10/0x12 [8812au]
[    3.163049]  ? rtw_5g_rates_init+0x1a/0x1c [8812au]
[    3.163065]  ? rtw_spt_band_alloc+0xb0/0xb2 [8812au]
[    3.163081]  rtw_wdev_alloc+0xf6/0x29c [8812au]
[    3.163096]  rtw_usb_if1_init+0xf0/0x20c [8812au]
[    3.163111]  rtw_drv_init+0x246/0x2d3 [8812au]
[    3.163145]  rtw_drv_entry+0x65/0x1000 [8812au]
[    3.314256] usbcore: registered new interface driver rtl8812au
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/VkPfMYyn4c/

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `dkms status` terminal command. Is Secure Boot disabled in BIOS? Please post the text directly without paste.ubuntu.com.

Comment: What does `sudo modprobe 8812au` output?

Comment: null output....

Comment: That's good. Then please add output of `usb-devices | awk '/17d2/' RS=`

Comment: T:  Bus=03 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=00 Cnt=01 Dev#=  2 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=0b05 ProdID=17d2 Rev=00.00
S:  Manufacturer=Realtek
S:  Product=802.11n NIC
S:  SerialNumber=123456
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#=0x0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 5 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=(none)

Comment: Please don't post this kind of information to comments. It's unredable here.

Comment: Please add output of `modinfo 8812au | grep -i 0b05`

Comment: alias:          usb:v0B05p17D2d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*

Comment: Does this help?  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1185952/need-rtl8814au-driver-for-kernel-5-3-on-ubuntu-19-10 as that driver should work for your device

Comment: @Jeremy31 Hold on. This driver should work.

Comment: Now please add output of `dmesg | grep 8812` TO YOUR QUESTION PLEASE

Comment: Hahaa :D i understand

Comment: There is some bug in this driver.  It is a correct one for this device, but it crashes for some reason. Try @Jeremy31 link. It should work. Remove `rtl8812au-dkms` first.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rtl8812au/+bug/1875016  Hopefully the dkms gets fixed also

Comment: @Pilot6 and Jeremy31 Thank you all

Comment: So does it work now? Then mark the question as a dupe.