# Netgear A7000 not working in 20.04

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, usb

I have a Netgear A7000 WiFi adapter that worked perfect on Win10 (I have decided to move to Ubuntu permanently, yay!).

After installing the drivers for the adapter by doing this:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git dkms
git clone https://github.com/zebulon2/rtl8814au.git
sudo dkms add ./rtl8814au 
sudo dkms build -m rtl8814au -v 4.3.21
sudo dkms install -m rtl8814au -v 4.3.21
```

the adapter still isn't even recognized as a USB device (there were no errors installing, then rebooted). It doesn't even light up on the adapter (I noticed it took a second to be turned on by Win10).

Here are things that may be important for this below:

lsusb output:

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 1532:0203 Razer USA, Ltd BlackWidow Chroma
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 046d:c07f Logitech, Inc. Gaming Mouse G302
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1532:0504 Razer USA, Ltd Razer Kraken 7.1 Chroma
```

iwconfig output:

```
enp9s0    no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

dkms status output:

```
nvidia, 450.80.02, 5.4.0-42-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia, 450.80.02, 5.4.0-54-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)
rtl8814au, 4.3.21, 5.4.0-54-generic, x86_64: installed
```

Thanks to anyone willing to help! I am still relatively new to Linux so I apologize for any frustration I cause.

**UPDATE:**
Upon running

```
sudo apt install net-tools
```

the dongle is found on lsusb and dmesg! To be honest, I don't know why. Ubuntu still doesn't recognize it, though. I will try a reboot!

Comment: Try a different USB port as it doesn't seem to be seen by Ubuntu

Comment: I am not sure that github site works with 20.04, if you see a new device in `lsusb` after plugging the dongle into a different port, see https://askubuntu.com/a/1185986/300665

Comment: @Jeremy31 Unfortunatly, after rebooting and trying multiple different ports, it doesn't seem to be an issue with the USB ports. I think the driver has to initiate the power on of the dongle or something like that; it did this on Win.

Comment: @Jeremy31 Just used that link's drivers, still not working

Comment: Open terminal, enter `tail - f /var/log/syslog` then insert the wifi card and post terminal output

Comment: If that device doesn't show up in `lsusb` no driver will work, we need to find out why it doesn't show

Comment: @jeremy31 Nothing comes up under standard input.