# Ubuntu 18.04: rtl 8812au wifi adapter driver dkms need to be manually rebuild every time kernel is upgraded

Tags: 18.04, kernel, dkms

Every time kernel is changed during dist-upgrade, Realtek 8812AU DKMS driver need to be recompiled manually because this is not done during dist-upgrade for new kernel automatically and driver failed to load on reboot:

```
[  491.302739] 8812au: version magic '4.15.0-124-generic SMP mod_unload' should be '4.15.0-128-generic SMP mod_unload'
```

This is result of long-existing bug in this package, it listed on launchpad as Bug IDs [1743849](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rtl8812au/+bug/1743849), [1804832](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rtl8812au/+bug/1804832), [1705820](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rtl8812au/+bug/1705820). Solution is to fix  MAKE line in dkms.conf in package to line below, but generally it should be done by package maintainer in repository (not done for 3+ years):

```
MAKE[0]="'make' all KVER=${kernelver}"
```

Is there any workaround to stay with repository 8812au dkms package version but automate rebuild 8812au on kernel change only, while package is still broken?

Some difficulty is that 8812au is an uplink interface for system affected and on reboot after kernel change it lost Internet connectivity if dkms is not recompiled and is unable to download any packages from repositories, so it should be done within dist-upgrade process or before reboot after dist-upgrade, or all needed for dkms build sources should be already downloaded to system.

Comment: It is a good question, but I wouldn't solve the problem this way. It is nuch easier to install anotter driver using a good dkms. There is nothing special with this package in Ubuntu repos. It is poorly maintained as you've noticed already.

Comment: See accepted answer in https://askubuntu.com/questions/1185952/need-rtl8814au-driver-for-kernel-5-3-on-ubuntu-19-10. The author also has a rtl8814au driver available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is to stop using broken and use good dkms as [heynnema](https://askubuntu.com/users/4272/heynnema) points above to accepted answer in [Need rtl8814au driver for kernel 5.3 on Ubuntu 19.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1185952/need-rtl8814au-driver-for-kernel-5-3-on-ubuntu-19-10). Working like an charm for nearly year now.