# i have a abgn ac wi-fi nano 11AC Adapter foktech. Can I get the driver for ubuntu

Tags: wireless, compatibility, adapter

AC600 Dual Band USB Adapter. I got it on amazon.co.uk .On the amazon website it doesn't say that it works on linux. Can anyone help. Thanks.

https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B06XZ5B5G9/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

---

Edit:

when I ran the command `lsusb` I got this:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 13d3:3529 IMC Networks Bluetooth Radio
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 13d3:5a11 IMC Networks USB2.0 VGA UVC WebCam
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0bda:c811 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 802.11ac NIC
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: So did you try it on Ubuntu? Which release? Does it work? What does `lsusb` show?

Comment: what's `lsusb` ?

Comment: `lsusb` is a terminal command that will show connected USB devices. We can see what chipset is used in this adapter.

Comment: I've put in what I got when I got `lsusb`

Comment: I linked a Q&A with the solution for this device.

Comment: The answer didn't work for me

Comment: I reopened the question. But "didn't work for me" won't bring us anywhere. Did the driver install properly, were there any errors, etc?

Comment: I don't think there were any errors. I did the procedure in terminal. the wifi isn't coming up  in settings or the top right-hand-corner of the desktop. I ran `sudo apt-get update` and restarted the computer. I still don't have anything when I have the dongle installed. Should I have the dongle installed when I do the installation in terminal. I don't think I had it installed when I installed the terminal process.

Answer (score 0):

Speaking from experience, this device does work with Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04, but you need to work for it.

These are the steps you'll need to follow:

0. If you don't already have `git` or `dkms` on your system, install them:

   ```
   sudo apt install git dkms
   ```
1. Clone the unofficial Realtek 8812au drivers to your local machine:

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/jeremyb31/rtl8812au-1.git
   ```
2. Change to the source directory:

   ```
   cd rtl8812au-1
   ```
3. Compile the driver:

   ```
   sudo ./dkms-install.sh
   ```

Once this is done, Ubuntu will recognize your WiFi adapter and it should work immediately after. If your WiFi settings are still greyed out, reboot and that should resolve the issue.

***Disclaimer:** I have not tested this on 12.04, 14.04, 16.04, or any non-LTS release of Ubuntu. If you are using something other than Ubuntu 18.04 or 20.04, your results may vary. Test often. Test well.*

Comment: I doubt that this will work. It is for `rtl8812au`, but OP has another device.

Comment: I don't think this works for me. I tried it, rebooted it and nothing has changed. Is there a setting to change. I have ubuntu 20.04. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

okay, I've solved my question. First tether usb to phone connection by connecting phone to computer by usb and configuring on phone settings 'tether'.

When you first install Ubuntu, in terminal use the command `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`.
Then in the command line [terminal] you should go back to the top directory.

```
sudo apt install git dkms
cd ~/
mkdir code
cd code
git clone https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au.git
cd rtl8812au
sudo ./dkms-install.sh
sudo make dkms_install
```

then reboot

[Reference for code above (1)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16384466/14915236)

[Reference for code above (2)](https://askubuntu.com/a/1185986/1176401)

As the question says above, you have to reboot twice. on the third reboot, the Wi-Fi [wifi] adapter dongle blue led light should flash every second.

Comment: Post results from terminal for `usb-devices | awk '/c811/' RS=`

Comment: I have no idea what your talking about? ... but my answer might help any 'noob' or 'stonk' to understand how to enable a wifi adapter with ubuntu.

Comment: Check in terminal `lsmod | grep cfg`  I don't think 88XXau works for your USB wifi as it should be a rtl8821cu device