# No option for WiFi on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS. Using a desktop with a shared Windows SSD and no ethernet cable

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 22.04

I'm using a TP-Link Archer T9UH usb WiFi adapter, but I need to know how to get the computer to detect WiFi in the first place so I'm not sure that information is of any importance yet.

I've done hours of troubleshooting and googling to the point where I'm convinced there's not even a solution. The only resolved post I found about this issue was solved because the guy's wife tripped over a cable. Not me. I have a flash drive at my disposal to download anything from my Windows partition onto (drivers?), and that's it.

Here's the lsusb result:

Bus 006 Device 002: ID 0781:5581 SanDisk Corp. Ultra

Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1532:0088 Razer USA, Ltd Gaming Mouse [Basilisk Ultimate, Wireless, Receiver]

Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2357:0106 TP-Link Archer T9UH v1 [Realtek RTL8814AU]

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

I see it's at least recognizing the TP-Link adapter I'm trying to use. My phone can't double as a hotspot so tethering isn't an option.

Edit: Not sure why the website marked this question as closed. The whole point of asking it is that I did NOT have access to a temporary connection. Closed but not resolved!

Comment: "I'm convinced there's not even a solution." There is almost *always* a solution. Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `lsusb` Can you tether your phone? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: This should work: https://askubuntu.com/a/1185986/1210606

Comment: I'm assuming I would need to already have an internet connection for that command in the link to work right?

Comment: Yes, any temporary connection will do, like the one you can get from tethering your phone.