# Drivers for TP-LINK Archer T2U PRO

Tags: drivers, wireless, kubuntu, tp-link

I followed instructions on [Need rtl8814au driver for kernel 5.3 on Ubuntu 19.10](https://askubuntu.com/q/1185952), but after `sudo make dkms_install` I got this error:

```
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for 8814au: 5.8.5.1 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.15.0-48-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/8814au/5.8.5.1/build/make.log for more information.
make: *** [Makefile:2410: dkms_install] Error 10
```

Answer (score 1):

The code in your link will not correctly compile in 5.15 and newer kernel versions. Instead, I recommend:

```
git clone https://github.com/morrownr/8814au.git
cd 8814au
sudo ./install-driver.sh
sudo modprobe 8814au
```

It might take a reboot.